# Installing .bundle VMware Client but says no module named sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, ubuntu, terminal, vmware

I am trying to install a .bundle and gives me an error and I can not see it in applications. I saw it is importing sqlite3 and I checked whether I have it or not. Then I installed but still can not use it or see it in applications. Should I install it elsewhere?

Edit: I understand it is looking a sqlite3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9
but it should look for it in /home/anaconda3/lib/python3.8 folder. How can I make it right?

[This is a screenshot of my Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2rRb.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pysqlite3
```

should do the trick.